# How to stack floated elements out of order

Tags: css, css-float

I have a responsive site with two columns.  The elements in each column are of variable height, so I don't think I can use CSS grid.  I want the elements on both sides of the page to stack up vertically without a gap between them.  When the screen size is reduced, I want the `div`s to remain in order and collapse into one column, so I can't put the elements in two separate containers.

Right now, each right hand column element is flush with the top of the preceding (longer) left hand column elements.  I don't understand why this is, as I thought floated elements were taken out of the flow.

Is there a way to get what I want?

```css
.left {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}

.right {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">

</div>

<div class="right">

</div>

<div class="left">

</div>

<div class="right">

</div>

<div class="left">

</div>

<div class="right">

</div>
```

I want two flush columns of boxes, with all the yellow boxes flush up against each other vertically.

Comment: I think the catch is that *everything* is floated so in effect everything behaves the same way (but different).

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for what is known as a [**masonry layout**](https://codeburst.io/how-to-pure-css-masonry-layouts-a8ede07ba31a). These are a bit tricky, but the aforementioned link might help :)